# Prove that this map is a conservative field.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $h:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Consider the following map $F: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by:
 $$F(x,y)=\left(y^2h(xy^2),2xyh(xy^2)\right).$$

Prove that this map is conservative.

I know how to prove this result assuming that $h$ is $C^1$. Because it's enough to prove the condition $M_y=N_x$. But in this case I can't do that.

If I try to solve the equation:

$$
f_x(x,y)=y^2 h\left(xy^2\right) \\
f_y(x,y)=2xyh\left(xy^2\right)
$$

Integrating with respect to $x$ the first equation we have:

$$f(x,y)= \int_{a}^{x}{y^2h\left(xy^2\right) dx}+g(y)$$

We have the following equation:

$$
g'(y)+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\int_{a}^{x}{y^2h\left(xy^2\right) dx}
 = 2xy h\left(xy^2\right)
$$

I don't know how to solve this =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $h$ is continuous on $\mathbf{R}$, it is integrable on $\mathbf{R}$.  Let $H$ be an antiderivative of $h$.  That is, $H'(x)=h(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbf{R}$.  Notice then, that $\frac{d}{dx}H(xy^{2})=y^{2}H'(xy^{2})=y^{2}h(xy^{2})$ for any constant $y^{2}$, by the chain rule.  Thus, $$\int_{a}^{x}y^{2}h(xy^{2})dx=\int_{a}^{x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}H(xy^{2})dx=H(xy^{2})|^{x}_{a}=H(xy^{2})-H(ay^{2})$$  Thus, you need to solve $$2xyh(xy^{2})=g'(y)+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\int_{a}^{x}y^{2}h(xy^{2})dx=g'(y)+2xyh(xy^{2})-2yh(ay^{2})$$ for g(y).

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion/Hint: Look at the lines:
$$
f_x(x,y)=y^2 h\left(xy^2\right) \\
f_y(x,y)=2xyh\left(xy^2\right)
$$
If $h$ is continuous, there is a function $H$ such that $H' = h$ - by the FTC. Can you see a way of making up your $f$ using $H$, and some expression involving $x$ and $y$ to satisfy the above two equations? (think the chain rule - you won't need an 'extra' $g$)

Comment: @Learning - do you see it?